# Parse request json size limit

Tags: parse-platform

I recently discovered Parse, and I want to use the push service. So this is how I plan to do targetted push:

1. Store the device tokens I got from Parse to my server, and associate every device token with matching user id.
2. When it's time to push, my server will tell Parse which device I want to push by using device tokens as the identifier.

I prefer sending all device tokens at once to Parse server instead of sending one by one, for the sake of reducing number of requests. What I'm worried about is Parse will reject my request because of the large list of device tokens. Does Parse have a limit of uploaded data size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit. Neither where clause nor data may exceed 64kB.